# In iText 7, How to know whether specific character exists in font?

Tags: fonts, character, itext7

In iText 7, How to know whether specific character exists in font?

In iText 5, I used below code.

```
Font font = FontFactory.getFont(fontName, BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
BaseFont baseFont = font.getBaseFont();
boolean isExist = baseFont.charExists(ch);
```

Is this possible in iText 7?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course

```
File windowsFontDir = new File("C:\\Windows\\Fonts");
for(File fontFile : windowsFontDir.listFiles()) {
    try {
        PdfFont font = PdfFontFactory.createFont(fontFile.getAbsolutePath());
        if(font.containsGlyph((int) 'a'))
        {
            System.out.println("Font " + fontFile.getName() + " has the required glyph.");
        }else
        {
            System.out.println("Font " + fontFile.getName() + " does NOT have the required glyph.");
        }
    }catch(Exception ex){}
}
```

This prints something like:

> Font AGENCYB.TTF has the required glyph.
>   Font AGENCYR.TTF has the required glyph.
>   Font ALGER.TTF has the required glyph.
>   Font ANTQUAB.TTF has the required glyph.
>   ...

Comment: Thank you very much, Joris. It was very helpful.

Comment: So, is this the accepted answer then? Hint hint ... :D

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure it will work for any font, because I haven't tested them all, but my first attempt would be to use the following method in `PdfFont`:

```
public abstract Glyph getGlyph(int unicode);
```

If the font does not contain a glyph for this Unicode code point, then this method should return `null`.

Comment: `containsGlyph` (proposed by @Joris) calls `getGlyph` *and* makes an extra test if a `Glyph` instance is returned